# Drawing dynamic graphs

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

Is it possible using java to create a dynamic graphs that update itself automatically when it receives values from outside?

I would create an application that check automatically the statistics of a server (data in,data out,etc...) drawing those values on the graph dynamically when those change.

I found `JFreeChart` but I don't know if it make those things

Comment: Of course you can, but your question is too general.

Comment: some tools,some particular code?

Comment: JFreeChart that you found seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [JFreeChart demo's page](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), Download the jnlp and launch it via Java Web start. There are plenty of JFreeChart examples with source code. In the samples directory tree, under "Miscellaneous -> Dynamic charts" you'll find what you need